# Comparing cells in one worksheet to columns in another and printing the rows that match in a third worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, vba

The data I am working with are strings, not integers.

I want to take two columns in worksheet1, say column B and D and compare them to two columns in worksheet2, say C and E.

If a cell in column B == a cell in column C and  a cell in column D on the same row as the cell in column B == a cell in column E on the same row as column C print the row that B and D are in next to the row C and E are in in worksheet3, if not, they don't need to be pasted into worksheet3.

How do I approach this? I have tried Vlookups, match, If statements and even some macro, however I have little experience with macro and am struggling terribly. Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thank you!

It won't let me post a picture that describes this easier so I apologize for the convoluted description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help ? 
(a formula to put in cells in sheet3)

```
=IF(Sheet1!B1=Sheet1!D1,Sheet1!B1,"")
```

Comment: That is the direction I need to go, however I need Sheeet1!B1 to be compared to the entire column of Sheet2!D

Comment: This is what I am currently trying, I moved all of the data to one sheet.

=IF(A2=(K2:K1000),IF(B2=(L2:L1000),(D20,P10),"no match"))